# Deny all outbound traffic except cloudwatch on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a server(Java/Tomcat running) which was creating huge outbound traffic. This server can not be accessed from outside world only internal network server can access it. i.e. inbound is allowed only from internal network.

To solve huge outbound traffic we have blocked all outbound traffic via aws security group except internal network servers.

But now it has also stopped aws custom monitoring scripts to send data to cloudwatch.

So ***what is the ip range*** that I need to open in outbound rules to send traffic to cloudwatch?

Comment: Whether you think that server is externally accessible or not, that "huge outbound traffic" is a massive red flag that it has been compromised.  The fact that it was able to generate such traffic suggests that it has external connectivity that you don't understand.  Blocking outbound traffic doesn't solve the real problem and your entire infrastructure could be at a substantial security risk until you shut it down and find the real problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Singapore region:

The Cloudwatch IP can be found if you ping the end point 
monitoring.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com
via any AWS server.

For any other region in AWS please refer to the link below.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#cw_region

The above page lists the endpoints of All the AWS services.

Comment: Try a *Start > Run> cmd > press enter > type* telnet cloudwatchURL to see any error messages,  as a plan B if the ping doesn't work

Comment: It is better **not to resolve the IP address of AWS endpoints** like that. I thought the endpoint should be a load balancer and [the load balancer IP address might be changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821333/amazon-ec2-elastic-load-balancer-does-its-ip-ever-change). I tried to resolve CloudWatch a few times and got some different IP addresses.

Comment: @Edward Samuel -- what should be the alternative if one is using AWS security groups ? Afaik the AWS Security group only allows rules based on IP - We can't put the endpoint URL in them ?