# AWS VPC - allow outbound traffic to AWS cloudwatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-vpc, aws-security-group

I'm struggling with isolate my instance from internet - I'm doing it by configuring Security Groups. Now I have problem that my logs can't be send to CloudWatch so I want to allow outbound traffic to logs.us-west-2.amazonaws.com but I'm not sure how to do it. This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32437103/deny-all-outbound-traffic-except-cloudwatch-on-aws) - the idea there was to add CloudWatch IP to outbound rules. This solution in my opinion is not ideal - we rely on single IP. Is there any better solution for this problem? I was thinking about adding rules for [aws-ip-ranges](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws-ip-ranges.html) but didn't find CloudWatch service there. Maybe someone of you know what range is for CloudWatch?

Answer (score 1):

For private communication with CloudWatch (CW) Logs, the best choice would be to use [VPC Interface Endpoints for CW Logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/cloudwatch-logs-and-interface-VPC.html).

This way, entire traffic between your instance and CW Logs **does not use internet** and happens within AWS private network.

If you want to deny all internet traffic from your instance, place it in **private subnet** without route tables to NAT gateway. The access to the CW Logs will happen through the prviate interface endpoint.