# How to get permanent ip address of a kubernetes load balancer service on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, kubernetes

How can I publish a service in an AWS kubernetes cluster at a permanent IP address, so that I can add a DNS record? I define service `xxx` of type `LoadBalancer` in kubernetes, and `kubectl describe service xxx` gives me something like:

```
LoadBalancer Ingress:   aae55ce563ca611e692c10a83aef9ddc-467886677.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:           <unset> 9004/TCP
```

Indeed, I can access the application on aae55ce563ca611e692c10a83aef9ddc-467886677.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com:9004. How can I make this a permanent IP address?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @error2007s said, you can't get a static IP for ELB. But if all you want is to assign a domain name to your ELB, then you can use a CNAME record pointing to `aae55ce563ca611e692c10a83aef9ddc-467886677.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com`. If you're using Route53 you can also define an alias for better performance. Create a record set under your hosted zone, choose type `A`, select Yes under "Alias: ", and finally select your ELB from the dropdown box.

Both options are documented by Amazon:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticLoadBalancing/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-domain-names-with-elb.html

Comment: Thanks for the exhaustive answer. I didn't realize there were other options than the A record.

Answer (score 2):

For AWS ELB you cannot make a permanent IP address as the IP address for AWS ELB is dynamic and changes frequently. So you have to use "aae55ce563ca611e692c10a83aef9ddc-467886677.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com" as the Canonical name for your application. Also refer this question [Amazon EC2 Elastic Load Balancer: Does its IP ever Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821333/amazon-ec2-elastic-load-balancer-does-its-ip-ever-change)