# How to make the ELB attach to a domain name in route53 in Kubernates deployments

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-elb

Currently I am doing deployment and creating a service with type loadbalancer. I can access the POD via the created ELB. Then using route 53 I am attaching the ELB with k8-test.abc.com using alias. Below is the snippet.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: %APP_FULL_NAME%-service-lb-http
  labels:
    appname: %APP_FULL_NAME%
    stage: %APP_ENV%
    component: app-kube-aws-elb
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "True"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:certificate/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http

spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    appname: %APP_FULL_NAME%
    stage: %APP_ENV%
```

But I was wondering is there any way by which I can do some changes on deployment and the ELB which will be created, automatically get attached to the k8-test.abc.com while creating.

Answer (score 2):

There is an Incubator project (read: you may use it, but don't complain if it breaks) called [external-dns](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns). I haven't used it myself, but it looks like it may do what you ask for. Among other DNS providers, it also offers support for Route53.

After set-up (here's [the documentation on how to set-up *external-dns* on AWS](https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/external-dns/blob/master/docs/tutorials/aws.md)), you can define a DNS name for a Service using the `external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname` annotation:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: %APP_FULL_NAME%-service-lb-http
  labels:
    appname: %APP_FULL_NAME%
    stage: %APP_ENV%
    component: app-kube-aws-elb
  annotations:
    external-dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/hostname: k8-test.abc.com
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-cross-zone-load-balancing-enabled: "True"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:XXXXXXXXXXXXX:certificate/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    appname: %APP_FULL_NAME%
    stage: %APP_ENV%
```

This will automatically create the respective DNS records that will alias the DNS name `k8-test-abc.com` to your ELB.

Comment: Thanks @helmbert. I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

By default it won't be automatic. You'll get an external endpoint for your ELB and then have to point your route53 at it.

This can mean that you have to do the pointing again if you recreate the Service, though not the Deployment so you can stick to rolling upgrades to avoid having to do much repointing.

There are other options to avoid this though, including NLB, Ingress and the external-DNS incubator project. The external-DNS approach would automate the route53 setup. The Ingress and NLB options still involve route53 but at least make sure you only have to do it once. For more on the Ingress and NLB approaches see the SO question [How to have the static ELB endpoint for kubernates deployments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880479/how-to-have-the-static-elb-endpoint-for-kubernates-deployments) I'd especially suggest looking at Ingress as it will also give you future flexibility to apply routing rules using paths and headers and would only require ELB and route53 setup once for the whole cluster (which means you only pay for one ELB).

Comment: you see I was using the same code as mentioned here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53880479/how-to-have-the-static-elb-endpoint-for-kubernates-deployments

I have already implemented ingress as well. So the architecture is like. I am having ngnix pod-> map to ngnix service - which is mapped to ngnix ingress. Now I am accessing that ingress with an ELB endpoint and which is link to my domain name in route 53. But as you correctly pointed out i have to point again if I re-create the service. That is why I looking for an option which will bind ELB endpoint directly at creation time

Comment: Well external DNS is a good option if you're ok to use a project which is in incubator. Personally I just deploy the ingress controller and its service once and then I don't change it after that.

Comment: I'll try that incubator project but I am looking for some reliable process(if available). Btw you are have the same architecture? I mean  deploy the ingress controller and its service with typeloadbalancer and using the ELB endpoint in route 53.?

Comment: Yeah I work on the Activiti project - we've an example where we recommend Ingress and DNS pointed at it https://github.com/Activiti/activiti-cloud-charts/tree/master/activiti-cloud-full-example and we have clusters where it runs, including an AWS one.