# How to set firewall rules that targets an AWS ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, firewall, amazon-elb

I have to set firewall rules on my network that targets an ELB. The load balancer belongs to another account, which I don't control. I also don't know if it is an Application Load Balancer or an Network Load Balancer.

When I `dig` the URL, it translates to a CNAME, that ends with `elb.amazonaws.com`. If i `dig` that as well, I end up with 4 different IPs.

Does AWS always keep the same 4 IPs for the same ELB, or it may change over time? How can I write firewall rules that targets an AWS ELB? Is there another way to approach this kind of problem?

Comment: ELB IP addresses change over time. You should add rules against the CNAME.

Comment: As far as I know AWS Route Tables don't accept names.

Comment: AWS Route Tables is for AWS resources. You practically have an external resource that you need to add rules for. IP addresses isn't an option. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821333/amazon-ec2-elastic-load-balancer-does-its-ip-ever-change